# NSDate in format dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I want NSDate in dd/MM/yyyy format, without its time i.e. hh:mm:ss format. I can get string in this format but not nsdate. How to get nsdate like 27/12/2013?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not really a duplicate since he says that he CAN get a string in that format (already), which is what that question and answer show.

Comment: Yes what @Inafziger is correct, it is not duplicate since I want in nsdate not in string format. In string I know how to convert, if there is any related link let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to format `NSDate` variables. In your case you would use it like this:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy";
NSLog(@"my date is %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourNSDateVariable]);
```

Comment: As I said I do not want in string format. I want in nsdate format.

Comment: you cannot set NSDate in any format, since it is a time value. When you print it out or display it, is when it gets formatted (and it is converted into a NSString).

Answer (score 1):

NSFormatter does this very well and easily:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSString *dateInString = [formatter stringFromDate:yourdate];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not "format" an NSDate, but instead only a string representation of it (which you say that you already know how to do).  Take a look at the NSDate class reference for more details: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *oldFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[oldFormatter setDateFormat: @"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *oldString = @"27/12/2013 21:30:21";
NSDate *theDate= [oldFormatter dateFromString:oldString];


NSDateFormatter *newFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[newFormatter setDateFormat: @"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *yourString = [newFormatter stringFromDate:theDate];
NSLog(@"%@", yourString);
```